# Android VideoView Overlapping

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, android-videoview, xamarin.forms

I have two pages in Xamarin Forms using a custom renderer to display an Android VideoView on each page. The video on Page1 (nested inside of a RelativeLayout) plays successfully. When I navigate from Page1 to Page2 using `Navigation.PushAsync(Page2);` the VideoView from Page1 continues to overlap the video on Page2.

**Is there a way to force the VideoView to respect the visibility of its parent view container?**

**Page1.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     x:Class="MyVideoApp.Page1">
        <RelativeLayout>
            <MyVideoView x:Name="vidPlayer" Source="http://...."
                  RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                  RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}" />
          </RelativeLayout>
        </ContentPage>
```

**Page2.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyVideoApp.Page2">

    <MyVideoView x:Name="vidPlayer" Source="http://...." />

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I have already tried using the OnAppearing() and OnDisapearing() in the Xamarin Forms page to set the visibility of the player to false when navigating to page two but no success. The VideoView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)
VideoView.setTranslationZ()
VideoView.setZOrderOnTop() methods also do not solve the issue.

Comment: Based on what I have found about SurfaceView it sounds like destroying and creating it when visibility comes back would be the way to go but not sure what that would completely look like.

Answer (score 1):

The `VideoView` is a `SurfaceView` and `SurfaceView`s Z-order are determined before being attached to a window and cannot be changed afterwards. So you cannot have multiple `SurfaceView`s showing at the same time since the `SurfaceView` kind of shows through anything and everything.

You may need to try removing the `VideoView` completely and re-adding it later or, if all else fails, you could try moving the `VideoView` off of the screen.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay%28boolean%29)

Comment: Interesting thought. I tried wrapping it in a Xamarin Forms frame and then removing it in OnDisappear(). That works except all the other elements on page 1 are still showing in addition to the stuff on page 2. Forms navigation must not like relative layouts when it tries to layer new screens within a single activity.